# How to zip align apk file that is created without coding? (I don't have the source code)

Tags: android

I have created my app on www.appyet.com without coding and I built my apk file, when I come to upload it to Google Play it requested a zip aligned apk, I really don't know what is zip aligning  and how to do that without having the source code??

Answer (score 0):

copy your apk to  adt> sdk > tools there exsists zip align tool then fire the command:

zipalign -f -v alignment infile.apk outfile.apk

alignment example 4

so fire the command

zipalign -f -v 4 infile.apk    outfile.apk

Answer (score 0):

To zip align your apk go to sdk tool can be found in

```
 ..\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0
```

and open command prompt there

and type zipalign -v 4 yourapprelease.apk outfile.apk

outfile.apk is the name you registered on playstore

further you can read here

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html